# How to clean change tracking to specific version?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, change-tracking

I'm using change tracking technology to synchronize two different databases A and B.

If anything is changed in A, I can identify these changes and send it to B. I'm also using own meta-table in DWH where are stored some important information about the last used CT version from the last synchronization.

There is a problem that default retention period is set to 2 days and auto_cleanup is set to ON. That means that after 2 days I would loose some changes if there will be any HW problem during synchronization longer than these 2 days. Of course I can set the retention period for longer period, nevertheless it won't solve it completely (if I would set retention period for X days, still there can be HW problem longer than these X days).

It would be the best to set auto_cleanup OFF and clean it every time after synchronization. So my question is:

> **"Is there any method how to manually cleanup change tracking just partially - till the some particular version?"**

*For instance:*

I would synchronize Contacts from A to B where the `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()` would be 4562. I would store this to my meta-table and run my manual cleanup function `MY_MANUAL_CLEANUP_FUNCTION(4562)` which clean all rows with CT_ID less than 4562. `CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION ( Contacts )` would return 4562.

Thanks in advance for any comments!